# Redirect immediately and continue background processing

Tags: asp.net

I have page 1.aspx which makes long processing, and I do not show results of calculations anywhere on this page. I want immediately redirect browser to 2.aspx, but continue execution of process in 1.aspx. Is it possible?

Comment: Use a Windows-Service that executes the long running taks. The database is the interface. It's possible(with threads) but IIS is not the best place for such time-consuming tasks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make a thread and let it run... Here an example with the option to pass parametres.

```
public class RunThreadProcess
{
    // Some parametres
    public int cProductID;

    // my thread
    private Thread t = null;

    // start it
    public Thread Start()
    {
        t = new Thread(new ThreadStart(this.work));
        t.IsBackground = true;
        t.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.MTA);
        t.Start();

        return t;
    }

    // actually work
    private void work()
    {
        // do thread work
        all parametres are available here
    }
}
```

and you run it as

```
  var OneAction = new RunThreadProcess();
    OneAction.cProductID = 100;
    OneAction.Start();
```

### Other way with only one function

```
  protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(new WaitCallback(ThreadProc));
        ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(state => Dokimes_Programming_multithread_QueryWorkThead.ThreadProc2());

        Debug.Write("Page Load ends.");
    }


    // This thread procedure performs the task.
    static void ThreadProc(Object stateInfo)
    {

        // No state object was passed to QueueUserWorkItem, so  stateInfo is null.
        Debug.Write(" Hello from the thread pool 1.");
    }

    static void ThreadProc2()
    {
        // No state object was passed to QueueUserWorkItem, so  stateInfo is null.
        Debug.Write("Hello from the thread pool 2.");
    }
```